# Put DIV ID into a PHP Variable

Tags: php, jquery

I am wanted to get the id's of all the divs on my page with the class `archive` and put them in a MySQL query to check and see if the ids are archived in the database.

So basically I am wondering how I can do this: `$div = $(this).attr('id');`

Then I would throw it into the loop to check:

```
$matches = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM content WHERE `div` = '$div'");
        while ($post = mysql_fetch_assoc($matches)) 
        {
            if (mysql_num_rows($matches) > 0)
            { 
              //DO THIS
            }
        }
```

UPDATE

I have this code for the AJAX now:

```
$('div.heriyah').each(function() { 
var curID = $(this).attr('id'); 
$.post("admin/btnCheck.php", { div : curID }, function(data) {
if (data == "yes") {
    $('#' + curID).html('<div class=\"add\"><div id=\"add_button_container\"><div id=\"add_button\" class=\"edit_links\">  + Add Element</div></div></div><div class=\"clear\"></div></div>');
} else {
    $('#' + curID).html('<div class=\"add\"><div id=\"add_button_container\"><div id=\"add_button\" class=\"edit_links\">  + Set As Editable Region</div></div></div><div class=\"clear\"></div></div>');
}
  });
});
```

And my PHP:

```
$matches = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM content WHERE `div` = '".$_POST['div']."'");
 if (mysql_num_rows($matches) > 0)
 { 
    echo "yes";
 } else {
    echo "no";
 }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `<div id="'; drop table students">http://bobby-tables.com</div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot throw a javascript variable to PHP script like that. You have to send an ajax request to the page

```
$div = $(this).attr('id');
$.post("yourquerypage.php", { divid : $div }, function(data) {
    // Something to do when the php runs successfully
});
```

Next, configure your query to get the variable from $_POST()

```
$matches = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM content WHERE `div` = '".$_POST['divid']."'");
```

And of course, you have to take measures for injection.

Comment: Thanks!  You have been really helpful!  I need to go through and fix my queries for injection prevention too!

Comment: I'm still a tad bit new to AJAX, but how to I check and set a callback function to see if there was data in the database that matched in an if/else format.

Comment: @drummer392, IF see in the above code, `function(data) {}` is the call back back function, `data` will hold everything that is echoed by the php page.

Comment: Thanks!  And then I can just write my if/else statements from there.

Comment: Can you have a look at the UPDATE I've added to my post to see what I am doing wrong.  I am not getting any result back from that.

Comment: @drummer392, see what `console.log(data)` has?

Comment: @drummer392, I meant the output

Answer (score 0):

It's simple syntax error. Remove the condition after the `else` and you should be fine.

```
else (data == "yes") { // remove (data == "yes")
    // snip
}
```

Comment: ok, I did that, but I think for some reason data isn't either sending or receiving back to the ajax.  I even just simply put `echo "no";` in the btnCheck.php file and still nothing.  The path is correct!

Comment: I think it'd be easier if you'd post a link to the site. What error are you getting?

Comment: The site is admin protected sadly, but I am not getting any error in Firebug.  But you are telling me that the code I have posted is correct(besides snipping that segment you posted)

Comment: how come your `else` has a `{` after it and a `}` at the end.  Mine doesn't look like yours.